# parallel query server died unexpectedly

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm running a SQL query, using Oracle sql developer, joining 4 tables on an AWS machine. Database is Oracle11g2.
Simple queries work fine but this specific query fails to run with the following error:

```
    12805. 00000 -  "parallel query server died unexpectedly"
*Cause:    A parallel query server died unexpectedly, PMON cleaning
           up the process.
*Action:   Check your system for anomalies and reissue the statement.
           If this error persists, contact Oracle Support Services.
           See trace file for more details.
```

The error is vaguely described in search results and no concrete solution has worked. Would be great to get help with this one.

Comment: Can you please share the query you are using? Also, would be nice to know if this same query works without the the parallel hint.

Comment: I cannot share due to policy but it's a regular query using 4 inner joins and a group by statement.

Comment: So, did you "see trace file for more details", as the error message suggested?

Comment: The same query works without the parallel hint?

Comment: You can limit parallel execution by explicit set on table level the parallel degree to 1 , eg ALTER TABLES sales PARALLEL 1;